# LineBreaker in Response not display Properly

Tags: android, android-volley, gson

[image]I have a problem with displaying Line Breaker in return response. When I check that text in different devices I got different symbols.
I have put way of set the response using gson & requested using Volley..

```
......
Gson gson=new Gson();
ItemsHolder = gson.fromJson(response.toString(),
                        ItemsHolder.class);
.......


......
 MenuItemsConfigurationListner configurationListner = new MenuItemsConfigurationListner();
        AuthonicateRequest jsonObjectRequest = new AuthonicateRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                url,
                (String) null,
                configurationListner,
                configurationListner
        );

        jsonObjectRequest.setTag(TAG);
        VolleySingleton.getVolleySingletonInstance().addToRequestQueue(
                jsonObjectRequest);
    ...............
```

Headers

```
private class AuthonicateRequest extends JsonObjectRequest {
        public AuthonicateRequest(int method, String url, String requestBody, Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
            super(method, url, requestBody, listener, errorListener);
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            return createBasicAuthHeader();
        }

        Map<String, String> createBasicAuthHeader() {
            Map<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headerMap.put(IConstants.CONTENT_TYPE, IConstants.APPLICATION_JSON);
            return headerMap;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is the text response from the server?

Comment: (Rich creamy chicken soup served with Garlic Bread)

Comment: when I test on Rest-client it just ignore that character and display like '(Rich creamy chicken soup servedwith Garlic Bread)'

Comment: Does it have a newline or break character?

Comment: not '\n' I think it break character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If response return from the server contains the line breaker this is the way of removing that and it replace with '\n' android studio supporting line breaker.

```
private class MyListener implements Response.Listener<JSONObject>, Response.ErrorListener {

            @Override
             public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
     Log.d(getTag() , error.toString());

                        }

             @Override
             public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
     MyItem item = new Gson().fromGson(response.toString(),MyItem.class);

     String desc = null != item.getContent() ? item.getContent() : getEmptyString()
                 desc = desc.replace("\u2028", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                 textViewItemDesc.setText(desc`enter code here`);
                         }
         }
```

Comment: I edited and added explanation I hope now it's understandable. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the text in a TextView, you can use

```
Html.fromHtml(yourText);
```

It converts basic html tags to corresponding `Span` and you can use the resulting `Spanned` string in your TextView.

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(yourText));
```

Comment: I tried following 2ways. But didn't work for me. String desc = null != menuItem.getContent() ? menuItem.getContent() : getNAString();
        textViewOrderItemDescription.setText(TextUtils.htmlEncode(desc));

        textViewOrderItemDescription.setText(Html.fromHtml(desc));